# CPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image:

Tags: tinymce, tcpdf

I have looked all over  trying to find an answer to this but none of the solutions worked out! 
I am trying to print out a PDF of a letter that someone creates with *TinyMCE*, the html text editor. We can print images from the web fine but when we try to hit pictures on the testing server we come up with

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image:
```

I have checked all the file permissions, *curl* and *allow_url_open* are both on/enabled.

I am pretty stumped please help if you can..

Comment: without code and some more info noone will be able to help

Comment: how is the image inserted in tinymce ? is it an absolute url ? does the image existe in your server ? can you view the image if you put it's url in the axplorer adress bar ? My guess is if you are using images that are in your server then the path isn't write , check the directory where the image is and compare it to the path where you generate your pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, when referencing your image in TCPDF do not use absolute links such as /images/myimage.png

TCPDF does not use the website home structure, it uses the base operating system directory structure.  So use a relaive link, such as:  images/myimage.png  if the folde images resided in the same folder as your tcpdf php file.  Or ../../images/myimage.png   if the it was below the tcpdf folder.

I had this same problem referencing my TTF font files.  Should be an easy fix.

Comment: I know this is years later, but I am also experience this. Where can one find the reference to the image link ? TCPDF is called from within the wordpress application, and I have no idea where to check and possibly edit the absolute link to my "ungetable image"